# Injetar serviço no provider da pagina.module

Tags: angular, ionic3

Eu estou trabalhando com **Ionic 3** e estou usando alguns de seus serviços nativos, como o login com o facebook. Tudo funciona perfeitamente, o meu problema está em algo que estou tentando fazer para organizar mais meu código.

Quando eu uso o plugin do facebook pela página `app.module` tudo funciona perfeitamente. Entretanto, por questão de organização, resolvi movê-lo para o mdulo da unica página que realmente o utiliza.

**Exemplo:**

Tenho as seguintes páginas `abertura.ts` e `abertura.module.ts`

Quando eu tento mover a importação do plugin do facebook da página `app.module.ts` para a página `abertura.module.ts`, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError[Facebook]:    StaticInjectorError[Facebook]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Facebook! Error: StaticInjectorError[Facebook]:    StaticInjectorError[Facebook]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Facebook!

Bom, basicamente ele está dizendo que não foi possível injetar o facebook em provider. Mas pq eu não posso fazer isso na página especifica que utiliza ele?

Meu código para a página `abertura.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AberturaPage } from './abertura';

import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import { LinkedIn } from '@ionic-native/linkedin';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AberturaPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AberturaPage)
  ],
  providers: [
    LinkedIn,
    Facebook,
    GooglePlus
  ]
})
export class AberturaPageModule {}
```

Comment: mete tambem o teu app.module.ts -- no entanto, o README do ionic-native diz-te explicitamente para meteres os native-modules a serem providenciados pelo app.module.ts

Comment: Pode compartilhar esse link para eu olhar?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/#installation < segundo ponto

Comment: Realmente ele diz isso. Mas não deixa claro se posso ou não adicionar no módulo da página. Ao meu ver, deixa o código bem mais limpo. Para mim o app.module deveria ser apenas para funcionalidades compartilhada entre várias páginas. Mas vou deixar como esta por enquanto. De qualquer forma valeu! ;)